# can we use multiple types of cache(redis & guava) in spring boot at the same time?

Tags: caching, spring-boot, redis-cache, google-guava-cache

I am trying to have two implementations of Cache for different type of objects in my spring boot application. I want to store certain objects in redis cache whereas other object in guava cache based on the method. Whenever I implement two calsses that extend CachingConfigurerSupport, I get an error that only one instance is allowed of this class. Could anyone suggest how I can do this?

Comment: This is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564285/how-to-setup-two-different-cachemanager-in-spring-boot/34587497)

Comment: So I need to annotate one of the implementation of CacheConfigurer and not the other? Could you please explain this with an example?

Comment: Just implement `CachingConfigurer` for the default one and register an extra bean of type `CacheManager` in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CompositeCacheManager like this,

```java
CompositeCacheManager compositeCacheManager = new CompositeCacheManager(
                ehCacheCacheManager(),
                redisCacheManager());
```

when use cache can specified cacheManage.

```java
@Cacheable(value = "firstCache", key = "#word", cacheManager = "ehCacheCacheManager")
```

Or

```java
@Caching(
            cacheable = {
                    @Cacheable(value = "firstCache", key = "#word", cacheManager = "ehCacheCacheManager"),
                    @Cacheable(value = "extendInfo", key = "#word", cacheManager = "redisCacheManager")
            }
    )
```

but i don't know how to update cache cascade.
hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following [blog](http://volodk.blogspot.com/2014/04/cascade-caching-with-spring-framework.html) show nice implementation.